# Graph API access to all public information?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I want to find users who have made their "favorite athletes" information public and who their favorite athletes are.  The support page says:

"The Graph API as such allows you to easily access all public information about an object. For example, https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor (Bret Taylor) returns all the public information about Bret."

However, I can only get information about Bret Taylor's favorite athletes here: "http://www.facebook.com/btaylor" as opposed to here "https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor".  Is it impossible to access the publicly available information about Bret Taylor's favorite athletes through the Graph API with only his ID (no access token).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I think so.

It's the same through the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=btaylor

Comment: Sorry, my question was unclear.  I am asking if it is possible to get the public information of an arbitrary user without an access token. For example, if I made my "favorite athletes" section available to the public in my profile, can the public access my "favorite athletes" section using the Graph API and my user id without an access token.

Comment: I understood this but maybe my response was unclear too.. In fact, I don't think this is possible. It seems that for Bret Taylor the data are public, but we can't access his data through the Graph API without an access key.

Comment: Oh i see, the "Yeah I think so" is in response to my "Is it impossible?"  Thanks for the answers.